# match_parent destroys complete layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a layout with an `ImageButton`. What I am trying to do now, is to put a `TextView` floating in the corner of that `ImageButton`. I replace the `ImageButton` with this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_notify"
            android:layout_column="2"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnInspect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="inspect"
            android:onClick="btnInspect_onClick"
            android:contentDescription="@string/inspect"
            android:src="@drawable/inspect" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

but, when the `ImageButton` is set to `android:layout_wdith="wrap_content"`, I can see in the visual view that the `RelativeLayout`'s width is how I want it, with the `ImageButton` filling only a part of that.

I'd reckon setting it to `match_parent` would fill it up completely. Instead, it destroys the complete layout. All elements (there are more in this view) are gone.

How can I replace an `ImageButton` with a `RelativeLayout` in my layout?

Comment: Maybe Framlelayout will be better for your use

Comment: @Chol you are right. That worked. Can I still float that `TextView` anywhere inside then?

Comment: My hint: Instead of using a RelativeLayout containing an ImageView and a TextView, a single TextView which includes a **compound drawable** is more efficient (1 View vs 1 ViewGroup and 2 Views).

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi also if that `TextView` is styled like a "unread messages" notifier, and might not be visible at all if there are no messages? The background drawable of the `TextView` is in fact a red circle.

Comment: I guess you can easily can manage the visibility of the whole TextView or just set its text color to transparent or to its normal color, depending on your needs - To let the background be visible all the time.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi if I would set the `TextView` to `GONE`, the entire button would be gone (don't want that). If I set it to `""`, the red circle would still be there (don't want that).

Comment: @Chol if you make your comment an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Then clear the background, too (set it to transparent)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104647/discussion-between-bart-friederichs-and-hrundi-v-bakshi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a relative layout you should use a FrameLayout in order to superpose 2 views

Answer (score 1):

why not just add an image as a drawable to the of your textview?
Like so

```
   <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_notify"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/inspect"
            android:layout_column="2"/>
```

That will be a more resource efficient way as you're suing less views

Comment: Which what I proposed in my comments, but the OP doesn't like this solution.

Comment: Because the design is *completely* different.

Comment: If you dont want the drawable to disappear when the textview's visibility is set to GONE. Why don't you just set it's text to empty instead of changing it's visibility?

Comment: @NizaSiwale It's useless. He does not want an **optimized approach**. I also told him that he can set the text and the background to empty instead of setting the visibility to GONE. But, no, "it's *completely* different".